# Web Page Wont Stop Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive recently added this bit of jQuery to my web page and now the website wont finish loading and the circle that spins is super annoying.

Can anyone help? The code is below:

```
    (function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = 1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(1000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
```

Comment: Your code here seems fine to me... When does it trigger? (is this code at the end of the page?) and is the loading of the quotes handled by separate client side code like a jQuery plugin?

Comment: @AshadShanto it doesn't look like that code should trigger any kind of loading. judging from the context, it seems to purposefully loop, hiding and showing elements with the class name `.quotes` one at a time.

Comment: Yeah the code is at the end of the page. No jQuery plugin. Can you give me an example of what it should be? Im a newbie and am not really versed with jQuery. Basically ive a set of 3 quotes that i just want to keep looping over and over but i want the page to stop perpetually loading. It was fine i think before adding this code.

Comment: Well, like i said, your code seems to do just that, and i don't think there is anything wrong with it.
Could we maybe see the rest of the page?
If it's a lot of code, try making a jsfiddle with everything in it here : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Taking a wild guess here : you could make sure the entire dom is loaded before running that code by using `$(document).ready(function(){showNextQuote()});`

Comment: @TimothyGroote Yes, that's right it was done on purpose. Got it.

Comment: Have you checked the network panel of the console to make sure that it is definitely this code that is causing the loading?

Comment: I think as @TimothyGroote said your code works fine. There might be  other issue that is making your browser loading. Take a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/5emr7bq2/

Comment: Im not sure what else it could be. Like i say, it worked fine before i added that code.

Comment: Sorry ignore me im being stupid. It was only perpetually loading on my localhost. It works fine live. Any suggestions as to why its doing this locally?

Comment: And as i say that it now doesnt load properly live either. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Well, good to hear you solved the problem anyhow.
Voting to close the question.